# What does this "PHP Fatal Error" mean?

Tags: php, soap, webservices-client

```
PHP Fatal error:
 Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soap:Server] System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapE xception: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.NullReferenceExcepti
on: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at _._.Application.SessionContext.ForeignAuthLogin(String username,
String password)
 at _._.Application.SessionContext.Login(String username, String password)
at -.-.Insert(String Username, String Password, String HandheldVersion, String CitationData)
--- End of inner exception stack trace --- in D:\Scripts\**********.php:3
```

basically i am trying to pass in certain parameters to a webservice call everything is fine as far as authentication because i've done this with other services, but this certain service is giving this error

sorry about the `_`, `-`, and `*` Im just trying to keep some of the names confidential

Comment: Welcome to the community! The next time you ask a question, please take the time to decide on a useful title, as well as make sure you mark up your code using markdown.

Comment: Do you have some purpose behind trying to delete this?

Comment: yes employer doesnt want this on here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the PHP SOAP client is throwing a [SoapFault](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.soapfault.php), but you're not catching it in a try/catch block.

The SoapFault appears to be thrown because the other end of the web service has an unhandled exception in its code... the stack trace being shown is actually from the .NET service on the other end.